# lPass by value & Pass by Reference

Tags: c#, .net, string, pass-by-reference

Could you please explain the following behavior of C# Class. I expect the classResult as "Class Lijo"; but actual value is “Changed”.

We’re making a copy of the reference. Though the copy is pointing to the same address, the method receiving the argument cannot change original.

Still why the value gets changed ?

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String nameString = "string Lijo";

        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = "Class Lijo";

        Utilityclass.TestMethod(nameString, p);
        string classResult = p.Name;
        Response.Write(nameString + "....." + classResult);
    }
}

public class Utilityclass
{
    public static void TestMethod(String nameString, Person k)
    {
        nameString = "Changed";
        k.Name = "Changed";
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

**Update**: When I pass a String, it does not get actually changed.

Comment: Might I suggest having a read of [Mr Skeet's excellent article on the subject](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: Even though String is an object, it's immutable, so when you pass a string the original reference is not modified

Comment: I had read this [article](http://zuta-developer.blogspot.com/2012/06/net-parameter-passing.html) This article will show you how parameter passing is handled in memory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The briefest answer is: read [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) which goes into this in a fair amount of detail.

The slightly longer answer is to compare these two methods, both of which use *value* parameters:

```
public void ChangeMe(string x)
{
    x = "changed";
}

public void ChangeMe(Person x)
{
    x.Name = "changed";
}
```

In the first case, you are changing the *value of the parameter*. That is completely isolated from the original argument. You can't change the content of the string itself, because strings are immutable.

In the second case, you are changing the *contents of the object which the parameter's value  refers to*. That's not changing the value of the parameter itself - it will be the same reference. To give a real world example, if someone delivers something to your house that changes the *contents* of your house, but it doesn't change your house's address.

If you changed the second method to this:

```
public void ChangeMe(Person x)
{
    x = new Person("Fred");
}
```

then the caller wouldn't see any change. This is closer to what you're doing with a string - you're making the parameter refer to a different object, rather than changing the contents of the existing object.

Now, when you use a `ref` parameter, the variable used by the caller as the argument is "aliased" with the parameter - so if you change the value of the parameter, that changes the value of the argument as well. So if we change the last method like this:

```
public void ChangeMe(ref Person x)
{
    x = new Person("Fred");
}
```

then:

```
Person y = new Person("Eric");
ChangeMe(ref y);
Console.WriteLine(y.Name);
```

this will print out "Fred".

The key concept to understand is that the value of a variable is never an object - it's either a value type value or a reference. If an object's data is changed, that change will be visible through other references. Once you understand that copying a reference isn't the same as copying an object, the rest falls into place reasonably easily.

Comment: Thanks. My brain is much relaxed now. May I take the freedom to ask the following questions? 1) Can I make my custom class immutable? Can I make my class a value Type (like int)? 3) What is the difference between object and Type? ["value of a variable is never an object - it's either a value type value or a reference"]

Comment: 1. Yes, you can definitely make your own immutable classes. Just don't provide any way of mutating it. 2. You can create your own custom value types, but they won't be classes - they'll be structs. 3. I'm not sure I really understand the question - but a value type value is something like "the number 3" or "the letter A" whereas a reference is a way of addressing an object, basically - it's an extra level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks. For concluding - is the following correct?

1. When a class is passed to a method without using “ref”, it is copying the memory address to a new reference object.  Hence the values in the memory location will get updated if any update is made to the object.

2. When a class is passed to a method using “ref”, its actual reference is passed to the method. If I make the reference to point to a different location, then on we will get access of the new memory location. The old memory location become unreachable.
Thanks

Comment: @Lijo: 1. The class isn't passed at all; a reference is passed. It's not a reference object, it's just a reference. There are no extra values being updated - it's just that changes made through one variable will be seen through other variables which reference the same object. 2. Again, don't think of it as a "class" being passed to the method. I typically think of it as a *variable* being passed, effectively... the parameter variable and the variable used for the argument are aliased. As for "unreachable" memory - that really depends on the exact situation.

Answer (score 7):

`Person` is a reference type, so no matter whether you use `ref`, `out` or nothing, you will always be able to modify it inside the method. You never pass the real person object to the method, you are passing the pointer as reference but not the actual `Person`. The `ref` keyword is useful with value types (such as structs, int, float, DateTime, ...). <strike>It could also be used with reference types but only to indicate behavior but cannot enforce it.</strike> If you use it with reference types it allows you to change the object this reference is pointing to.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "the `ref` keyword is useful only for value types". If you use it with reference types, it allows you to change the object that the parameter points to, which can be very useful in some circumstances.

Comment: Not quite true, you can still pass a reference type by `ref` and it will be subtly different because it will allow you change what the original reference is pointing too.

Comment: @Mark, @Alconja, I agree with you and I've updated my post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: "It could also be used with reference types but only to indicate behavior but cannot enforce it." - No, that's definitely not right. Using "ref" with a reference type parameter changes the behaviour in the same way as it does with value types: a change to the *value of the parameter* will be seen by the caller.

Comment: @Jon, what I meant is that even if a reference type parameter is passed without the `ref` keyword it can be modified inside the method.

Comment: @Darin: Yes, but the way you've phrased it about "indicating behavior" is misleading IMO. I think your answer would be better if you removed that sentence. In particular, you definitely *shouldn't* use `ref` to indicate that the contents of an object might change - you should use it to indicate that a method wants to be able to change the value of the argument itself.

Comment: @Jon, now that I read my answer I see that it makes no sense :-) I don't know what was I thinking when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass P to a test method you pass its location in the memory, rather than the copy of the object. Reference gets picked up in the body of the method and the original value gets modified.

Answer (score 0):

`Utilityclass.TestMethod` cannot change the local variable `p` to point to a different `Person` object since you are not passing by reference, but it is still free to call any methods or change any properties on the object it is passed. So the `Name` property can be modified within `Utilityclass.TestMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been mostly answered, but I think you might like to try out this snippet (bonus points if you try this out with ints!)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = "Class Lijo";

        Utilityclass.TestMethod(p);
        string classResult = p.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(classResult);
        Utilityclass.TestMethod2(ref p);
        classResult = p.Name;  // will bomb here           
        Console.WriteLine(classResult);
    }
}

public class Utilityclass
{
    public static void TestMethod(Person k)
    {
        k.Name = "Changed";
        k = null;
    }

    public static void TestMethod2(ref Person k)
    {
        k.Name = "Changed Again!";
        k = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you pass a reference type argument to a method, this means that the method has direct access to that argument not to a copy of it....

So the result is Changed.

Comment: No, it has a copy of the argument - but that argument is a reference, not the object itself.

Comment: You mean the address of an object is copied...right?
What I meant by direct access was the same as yours. wasn't it?