# pass by reference and not returning a value

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a method that calls another method with some parameters, something like this:

```
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      List<SomeObject> TheList = SomeQueryThatReturnsTheList();

      TheList = DoSomeWorkWithList(TheList);
   }

   public List<SomeObject> WorkForList(List<SomeObject> TheListAsParameter)
   {
      foreach (SomeObject x in TheListAsParameter)
      {
          ....
      }

      return TheListAsParameter;
   }
```

As you can see, the method `WorkForList` returns the list it received. My question is this: if I don't return the list and rewrite the signature as `public void WorkForList(List<SomeObject> TheListAsParameter)` is pass by reference in c# going to mean that TheList in `SomeMethod` is going to be updated with the work that's done in the `WorkForList` method? If so, will the following code work the same:

```
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      List<SomeObject> TheList = SomeQueryThatReturnsTheList();

      DoSomeWorkWithList(TheList);
   }

   public void WorkForList(List<SomeObject> TheListAsParameter)
   {
        ....
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves so many downvotes, its a valid question and I have seen lots of developers confused about the concept of parameter passing in c#

Comment: @Habib It shows a lack of basic research regarding passing by reference vs passing by value. These concepts aren't C# specific and have been documented many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Pass by value & Pass by Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910582/c-sharp-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you don't use the `ref` keyword, **its address will be passed by value,** meaning you will be able to change its element, but you can't initialized it or can't assign it null. for example. If in your method you do:

```
public void WorkForList(List<SomeObject> TheListAsParameter)
{
  TheListAsParameter = null;
}
```

You will not see the difference in the caller.

You should see this article: [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: Can you check with lngo's answer? Seems that it conflicts.

Comment: @frenchie, Ingo's answer is correct with respect to `foreach` loop, but has nothing to do with parameter passing

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the code will do what you want to do, **BUT** bear in mind two things:

- C# is "pass by value" language. It passes the address of the object, so this will only work if you work with this instance, not change the instance itself. For that, you should use `ref` keyword, but that usually ends up with harder to read code.
- returning objects vastly improves readability - what you do is considered a side-effect, a user of your method (another team member maybe) may not be aware you are modifying the list contents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. But returning the object might be useful, for clarity, and to allow methods chaining.

For example with your first `WorkForList` method :

```
yourObject.WorkForList(list).DoSomethingWithTheReturnedList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this should behave exactly as you've described... Surely you can just test the code you've already written?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as your `WorkForList()` method doesn't have a line like this:

```
TheListAsParameter = something;
```

then any changes you make to `TheListAsParameter` will be reflected in the calling method without returning it.

To speak precisely here, in this case you aren't passing a variable by reference. You are passing a reference type by value. Pass by reference involves the use of the `ref` keyword in C#.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use foreach to modify values of the list:

```
  foreach (SomeObject x in TheListAsParameter)
  {
      ....
  }
```

As you are not allowed to modify the contents of a Collection you are walking through using foreach.

Comment: Well actually the method DOES use a foreach loop, can you clarify?

Comment: c# will not allow you to modify x in that case giving you some error message like 'Cannot assign to x... because it is a 'foreach iteration variable', meaning foreach loops in c# are exclusively meant for iteration through collections to read information and you will not be able to write data into the iteration variable

Comment: Can you check with Habib's answer? Seems like it conflicts.

Comment: MSDN states it clearly, no need to check with habibs answer:  The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.110).aspx ... in addition the compiler also wont allow you to modify data

Comment: This is a fundamental limitation on modifying collections.  It has nothing to do with how you pass it to the method or whether you return it afterwards. Trying to modify a `List<T>` while iterating through it in a `foreach` will produce an exception.

Comment: On the other hand, that means that this answer is mostly irrelevant to the question and it does leave out the very relevant information that is in Habib's answer.