# Memory allocation with MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, memory

My question is quite simple..

When passing a MemoryStream object does the inner buffer (of byte[]) is allocated again in the memory?

The question comes from the place of memory fragmentation, which can be problematic in large scale system.

Comment: What do you mean "passing" the stream? Do you mean passing it from one method to another? That has no impact on memory allocation.

Comment: Yes i mean passing the stream as a parameter to method, or in ctor. So the inner byte array does not get reallocated?

Comment: Do you have a specific scenario? For example, if you declare byte[100] and give it to a memory stream then that's 100 bytes plus change. But if you get a byte[] representation of say, an xml file, now you have a copy of the xml file and the byte array in memory.  I don't have a decompiler handy but they say the MemoryStream is just a wrapper around a byte array. So there wouldn't be a reason to have multiple copies of it inside.

Comment: This is not memorystream specific. This is basic C#/CLR knowledge (ref types). The rule is the same for all ref types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Pass by value & Pass by Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910582/c-sharp-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 4):

That depends. If you initialise a MemoryStream from a byte[] via the constructor, then: no. The MemoryStream will refuse to resize as it is is just a window over your existing buffer.

If you create a new MemoryStream *without* passing in a buffer, then you Write a buffer to the Memory stream - then: yes. In this case the buffers are unrelated even if they happen to have the same byte contents.

Edit: to clarify - I'm only referring to *construction*. After that, when you pass it around: no, of course it isn't duplicated. It is a class: you're only passing a reference to a single object.

Comment: +1 for some reason I recalled the boolean parameter was for resizing ;p

Answer (score 3):

No.  When passing any object, you are simply passing a reference to that object.  You are still referencing the same `MemoryStream`, which is still referencing the same inner buffer.  Nothing is re-allocated.

Answer (score 1):

In C# every non-value type is really a reference under the hood, so when you pass a MemoryStream to a method, you should only be passing the reference to the MemoryStream, not a copy of the MemoryStream.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_referencetypes

Comment: Every *class*, is a reference type.  User defined structs are value types, not reference types.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, a basic type is called a value type in C#, and is something like int or decimal, or a struct.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: "basic types" and "non-basic types" are not terms defined in the C# specs, nor are they commonly used terms withing the C# community, so at best your definition is vague and unclear.  Note that your link doesn't use the word "basic" anywhere.  The closest term that comes to mind would be a "build int type" which [is referenced in your link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx), but that not only doesn't include all value types (it excludes user defined structs as well as enumerations) but even includes several reference types (`string` and `object`).

Comment: I went to school before C# existed.  Edited wording in answer.